# Load YAML File in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a bunch of settings and configs that I need AWS Lambda to be able to access. This is not a .py file, so I cannot just import it. In order to load the YAML, I need to specify a path to the file, so how do I do that in Lambda?

My understanding is that Lambda can only read/write to the /tmp folder. But I would like to include this config file with either the lambda layer or as a file in the lambda code package. Either of those two options are not in the /tmp folder and therefore does not provide direct read/write to files there.

Where can I put this YAML file and how can I reach it to read it during runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Lambda has read access to everything. It only has write access to the `/tmp` folder. If you are thinking about including the YAML file in a Lambda layer, or in the code package, your code will be able to read the file just fine.